GitHub tests take a long time
I have created the following /.github/workflows/testing.yml file:
name: Linting-And-Testing

on: [push, pull_request]

jobs:
  Linting-And-Testing:
    name: Linting-And-Testing
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Install Dependencies
        run: npm install
      - name: Run linting
        run: npm run lint
      - name: Run tests
        run: npm test

The linting part of this file is correctly completed in seconds. However, the testing takes a long time.
When I manually run the tests for the same code on my computer, the tests finish running in seconds. However, on GitHub, they can take 6 hours to run.
The tests running are creating, reading, updating and deleting data from a Realm database.
An example of some of the tests:
describe("table", () => {
    let realm;

    beforeEach(() => {
        realm = new Realm({ "schema": [table] });
    });

    afterEach(async() => {
        realm.write(() => {
            realm.deleteAll(); // Clear all data in the database
        });
        await realm.close(); // Ensure Realm is closed after each test
    });
    
    test("Create table", () => {
        expect(realm.schema[0].name).toBe("Table");
    });

    test("Create record in table", () => {
        realm.write(() => {
            realm.create("Table", { "id": 1, "name": "Name", "notes": "Notes" });
        });
        const table = realm.objects("Table")[0];
        expect(table.id).toBe(1);
        expect(table.name).toBe("Name");
        expect(table.notes).toBe("Notes");
    });
});

I assume the reason is because the tests are running on Ubuntu instead of an Android or iOS device. If this is the reason, how would I be able to run the tests on an Android and iOS device.
